# QtCreator or QtSDk

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have to use OpenCV with Qt for developing C++ application then which QT I should use QtCreator or Qt QtSDk?

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator is just an IDE which works with Qt-SDK as a C++ framework.

The major thing is Qt-SDK, but get both of them. As a beginner to Qt, I suggest you use QtCreate and Qt-SDK together.

Comment: can you tell me how to install it with opencv.I dont understand how to give qt's path in opencv

Comment: are u forgot to give the link?

Comment: @RashmiSargar: No, click on this word of my first comment :-)